# How to use gnu sort to sort lines with field delimiter present only on some lines

Tags: sort

In my .vimrc I list my vundle bundles like so:

```
cat ~/.vimrc

...
Bundle 'Raimondi/delimitMate'
Bundle 'kien/ctrlp.vim'
Bundle 'matchit.zip'
Bundle 'upAndDown'
Bundle 'rking/ag.vim'
...
```

Now, I would like to quickly sort my Bundle list by the bundles name, which works for lines where `/` is present, like so:

```
cat ~/.vimrc | sort -t "/" -k2,2

...
Bundle 'matchit.zip'
Bundle 'upAndDown'
Bundle 'rking/ag.vim'
Bundle 'kien/ctrlp.vim'
Bundle 'Raimondi/delimitMate'
...
```

How would I sort lines where there is no`foo/` prepended to the bundles name, as is the case e.g. for `Bundle 'matchit.zip'`?

Answer (score 1):

You could always prepend a `./` and then remove it again. Eg:

```
sed "/\// ! s:^Bundle[[:space:]][[:space:]]*':&./:" ~/.vimrc |
  sort -t "/" -k2,2 |
  sed "s:\(^Bundle[[:space:]][[:space:]]*\)'\./:\1:"
```

Or with GNU `sed`, this can be shortened slightly with extended regular expressions:

```
sed -r "/\// ! s:^Bundle[[:space:]]+:&./:" ~/.vimrc |
  sort -t "/" -k2,2 |
  sed -r "s:(^Bundle[[:space:]]+)'\./:\1:"
```

Or just use a single literal space if you are sure the file is consistent.

Comment: Thank you @Graeme for your suggestion. 

I was hoping it could be possible to let solely `sort` itself to do the job, without the roundtrip over `sed`.

I'll leave this open for now, in the hope that someone still comes with a terser solution